# R: subsetting rows in dataframe by factors in column

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe df, which consists of a large number of rows and several columns. I would like to remove a range of rows depending on the content in column x6 (see code below):

For this I have coded:

```
subset(df, x6 == "1 -Energy", "2 - Industrial Processes and Product Use", "3 
- Agriculture", "4 - Land Use, Land-Use Change and Forestry", "5 - Waste 
management", "6 - Other Sector")
```

This command is not permitted by R and I'm wondering what I need to change?

Thanks for every kind of help. Thanks again!

Nordsee

Comment: Like this:  `subset(df, x6 %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might mean this command instead:

```
subset(df, x6 %in% c("1 -Energy", "2 - Industrial Processes and Product Use", "3 - Agriculture", "4 - Land Use, Land-Use Change and Forestry", "5 - Waste management", "6 - Other Sector") )
```

beware the %in% operator.